# What is more correct to use to centralize this case

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to centralize `frm_login` using `pack` or `grid` without using another auxiliary widget. Is it possible?

I put an `anchor="center"` in `frm_login.pack(side="left")` but it didn't work.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

principal = tk.Tk()
principal.title("Login")
principal.resizable(False, False)
largura = 300
altura = 200
posx = int(principal.winfo_screenwidth() / 2 - largura / 2)
posy = int(principal.winfo_screenheight() / 2 - altura / 1.2)
principal.geometry("{0}x{1}+{2}+{3}".format(largura, altura, posx, posy))

frm_login = ttk.Frame(principal)
frm_login.pack(side="left")

lb_usuario = ttk.Label(frm_login, text="Usuário")
lb_usuario.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=5, pady=5, sticky="e")
ed_usuario = ttk.Entry(frm_login, width=24)
ed_usuario.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="w")

lb_senha = ttk.Label(frm_login, text="Senha")
lb_senha.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=5, pady=5, sticky="e")
ed_senha = ttk.Entry(frm_login, width=24)
ed_senha.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky="w")

frm_botoes = ttk.Frame(frm_login)
frm_botoes.grid(row=2, column=1, pady=5, sticky="w")
bt_entrar = ttk.Button(frm_botoes, text="Entrar")
bt_entrar.grid(row=1, column=1)
bt_sair = ttk.Button(frm_botoes, text="Sair")
bt_sair.grid(row=1, column=2)

principal.mainloop()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the tkinter `grid` method and pass your parameter `sticky="nsew"`. Use `rowconfigure()` and `columnconfigure()`. Set the parameter `weight=1` in `rowconfigure` and `columnconfigure`. So your widget is going to fill in the whole space they can using sticky. When you configure row and column, only the rows and columns you specified are going to be in the frame with equal weight if all are configured the same. This code should work:

Note: You can use `padx` and `pady` if the frame is expanding too much. Use them when you are calling `grid()` but entirely depends on your purpose.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

principal = tk.Tk()
principal.title("Login")
principal.resizable(False, False)
largura = 300
altura = 200
posx = int(principal.winfo_screenwidth() / 2 - largura / 2)
posy = int(principal.winfo_screenheight() / 2 - altura / 1.2)
principal.geometry("{0}x{1}+{2}+{3}".format(largura, altura, posx, posy))

principal.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
principal.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

frm_login = ttk.Frame(principal)
frm_login.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

frm_login.rowconfigure((0, 1, 2), weight=1)
frm_login.columnconfigure((0, 1, 2), weight=1)

lb_usuario = ttk.Label(frm_login, text="Usuário")
lb_usuario.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=5, pady=5, sticky="e")
ed_usuario = ttk.Entry(frm_login, width=24)
ed_usuario.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="w")

lb_senha = ttk.Label(frm_login, text="Senha")
lb_senha.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=5, pady=5, sticky="e")
ed_senha = ttk.Entry(frm_login, width=24)
ed_senha.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky="w")

frm_botoes = ttk.Frame(frm_login)
frm_botoes.grid(row=2, column=1, pady=5, sticky="w")
bt_entrar = ttk.Button(frm_botoes, text="Entrar")
bt_entrar.grid(row=1, column=1)
bt_sair = ttk.Button(frm_botoes, text="Sair")
bt_sair.grid(row=1, column=2)

principal.mainloop()
```

Hopefully this answers your question.

Comment: Thanks ss3387, your code is functional and it clarified for me a new way of working with grid. I made some changes and it was just what I wanted. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

If you add `expand=True` to the call to `pack`, it will be centered. `expand` tells the packer to expand the allocated space to consume all extra space. By default the frame will be centered in the space allocated. The net result is that the frame will be centered in the window.

```
frm_login.pack(side="left", expand=True)
```

Answer (score 2):

I think this will answer your question. When you are using tkinter `.grid` to place your elements, you can define the weight of each column and each row. An example is the following: Let's say that I want my column number 0 to occupy less than my column number 1, for this:

```py
main.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
main.grid_columnconfigure(1, weight=3)
```

In this example, the column number 1 triples the value of column 0.

This way, the elements that are placed in a column will adjust to the weight of that same column. You can do this with each column and with each row. Greetings and good luck!